# Why is gitlab-registry.key "skipped due to only_if"?

Tags: docker, authentication, gitlab, registry, gitlab-omnibus

Using Docker and Compose, I'm trying to pair Gitlab with an external Registry running as another service. I'm using Traefik to do so. In order to pair the Gitlab and Registry services, I need Gitlab to create a key at `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab-registry.key`, but I can see in the logs during startup that it's not happening... I suspect I've not set all the environmental variables I need to??

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: "traefik:v2.2.0"
    hostname: "traefik.${WEBSITE}"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "5000:5000"
    command: --configFile=/config/traefik.toml
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik:/config:ro"
      - "/certs/letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json"


  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    hostname: "git.${WEBSITE}"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.git.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.git.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.git.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.git.rule=host(`git.${WEBSITE}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.git.service=git"
      - "traefik.http.services.git.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    ports:
      - "22:22"
    environment:
      gitlab_omnibus_config: |
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22
        external_url "https://git.${WEBSITE}"
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        nginx['http2_enabled'] = true
        nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
          "host" => "$$http_host",
          "x-real-ip" => "$$remote_addr",
          "x-forwarded-for" => "$$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
          "x-forwarded-proto" => "https",
          "x-forwarded-ssl" => "on"
        }
        # Registry settings
        registry['enable'] = false
        gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
        gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "registry.${WEBSITE}"
        gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5000"
        gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry"
        gitlab_rails['registry_key'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/certificate.key"
        gitlab_rails['registry_api_url'] = "https://registry.${WEBSITE}:5000"
        gitlab_rails['registry_issuer'] = "gitlab-issuer"


  registry:
    container_name: registry
    image: registry:2.7
    hostname: "registry.${WEBSITE}"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry.entrypoints=registry"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry.rule=Host(`registry.${WEBSITE}`)"
    volumes:
      - "/data/registry:/registry"
      - "/certs:/certs"
    environment:
      REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /registry
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: 'true'
      # REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM: "https://git.${WEBSITE}/jwt/auth" # <--- requires gitlab-registry.key
      # REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE: container_registry # <--- requires gitlab-registry.key
      # REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER: gitlab-issuer # <--- requires gitlab-registry.key
      # REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE: /certs/gitlab-registry.crt # <--- requires gitlab-registry.key
```

traefik/traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.registry]
    address = ":5000"

[providers]
  [providers.docker]
    exposedByDefault = false

[certificatesResolvers]
  [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme]
    email = "noreply@example.com"
    caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    storage = "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlsChallenge]
```

I have an environmental variable, **WEBSITE**. After starting this Docker container using `docker-compose up -d`, I can access Gitlab fine at https://git.[WEBSITE]. Also I can reach the container catalog using `curl -k -X GET https://registry.[WEBSITE]:5000/v2/_catalog` (unless I comment out the block of REGISTRY_AUTH environmental variables).

I can see the part in the Gitlab startup logs where it's skipping the key creation, but cannot figure out why... any ideas?

Startup logs (can be viewed using `sudo docker logs -f gitlab`):

```
...
...
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/backups] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/backups] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci] action create (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab-registry.key] action create (skipped due to only_if)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc] action create
    - create new file /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc
    - update content in file /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc from none to 7b16c8
    --- /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc    2020-04-21 02:11:21.628290241 +0000
    +++ /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/.chef-gitlab-rails-rc20200421-31-y0rbxu    2020-04-21 02:11:21.628290241 +0000
    @@ -1 +1,6 @@
    +gitlab_user='git'
    +gitlab_group='git'
    +registry_dir=''
    +registry_user='registry'
    +registry_group='registry'
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.secret] action delete (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/secret] action delete (up to date)
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From Gitlab issues, it seems some services are not starting up properly before you do the configuration. Check out this thread: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4257#note_171862038.